# Черный фон у Layout

Tags: android

Есть лейаут А, который перекрывается лейаутом Б. У обоих лейаутов установлен фон. на телефонах 2.3.7 и ниже все ок. На 4х версиях после скрытия Б, у А фон черный.
Пробовал при скрытии Б прописывать для А invalidate() - не помогло.
Подскажите что делать?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте *android:cacheColorHint* выставить в *[@android](/users/8445/android):color/transparent*.

Или для стиля темы поставить

```
<item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
<item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/translucent_background</item>
```

Где *@drawable/translucent_background*:

```
<drawable name="translucent_background">#00ffffff</drawable>
```

Comment: Это помогает только для ListView (да и то не всегда). А у Layout вообще такого свойства нет.

Comment: таким образом там уже задан фон приложения (не черный)